# Rails, DNSimple, Heroku and SSL - do I need a certificate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, dnsimple

So I'm currently deploying my app via Heroku. I noticed that in my-app-name.herokuapp.com has HTTPS, so if I do `config.force_ssl = true` in my `environments/production.rb` it seems like I have wildcare SSL, right?

Now I'm using DNSimple to get my actual name - call it my-app-name.com. Which currently resolves to http://my-app-name.com, but really is just a namespace for .

So I guess I'm wondering, given that I'm technically still hitting my herokuapp, cam I covered by the wildcard SSL certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just went through this same scenario. The certificate you see in your `herokuapp` is the wildcard certificate issued for `*.herokuapp.com`.

If you want to secure a custom domain name `http://my-app-name.com`, you would  need to purchase and install your own wildcard certificate via DNSimple.

Comment: Kind of what I figured. But not really what I wanted to hear ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a custom domain, with a Heroku app and a free SSL certificate it's worth checking out [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) as your DNS service. The free product includes a shared SSL certificate much like the Heroku one!